# rosmaster dies all nodes need to restart

Tags: ros, rosmaster, nodes, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am finding that if the the rosmaster node is rebooted on one machine and rosmaster is restarted I am finding I am having to restart all the other nodes on the remaining computer. Is their some how a way to prevent the need to restart the other nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227935/rosmaster-dies-all-nodes-need-to-restart/) by [mpatalberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/23552/mpatalberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is not possible, when a node starts it will registers the topic it listens/subscribes to the rosmaster. So once the master is killed, the connection is lost. You might use roslaunch to easily start/stop the whole thing

---

Originally posted by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) with karma: 381 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2